# Is there a way to print the json representation of an object to the browser in Polymer?

Tags: polymer

In AngularJS I would use:

```
<pre>{{object|json}}</pre>
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in PolymerJS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation of a custom `json` filter is quite simple:

```
<script>
  PolymerExpressions.prototype.json = function(object) {
    return JSON.stringify(object);
  }
</script>
```

Then you can use `{{object|json}}` anywhere you like.

Comment: Note that PolymerExpressions is no longer available in Polymer 1.x. See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#expressions-in-binding-annotations

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so out of the box, you could create a custom element and just render your object as:

```
JSON.stringify(object)
```